# Speed up ruby select id query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

having a bit of a headache with this one, i currently have code that looks like this:

```
  tmarray = TM.select(:id).where('product_name ILIKE ? AND valid_from = ? AND promotional_text ILIKE ?', "#{eventname}%", "#{row.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}", "#{row.eventvenuename}")
  if tmarray
    tmarray.each do |tm|
      tm.update(event_id: row.id)
    end
  end
```

This is currently taking over 3 hours to run on 30,000 rows.

What would be the more speed efficient way to do this?

I have been looking at ActiveRecord import but not 100% sure how I would go about making it work for an update?

Thanks

**Edit**

Heres the full code:

```
task populate: :environment do
  begin
    Event.all.each do |row|
      eventname = row.eventname
      if eventname.include? "UnderGround Presents "
        eventname = eventname.gsub('UnderGround Presents ', '')
      end
      if eventname.include? "&"
        eventname = eventname.gsub('&', 'and')
      end
      tm_array = TM.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND valid_from = ? AND promotional_text ILIKE ?', "#{eventname}%", "#{row.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}", "#{row.eventvenuename}")
      tm_array.find_each do |tm|
        tm.update(event_id: row.id)
      end

    end
  rescue Faraday::TimeoutError
    puts "Connection failed"
    next
  end
end
```

Comment: Where's the slowdown? I mean, you're doing a `like` on text values--is it indexed? What DB? What do you have in place for text searches?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure where the slowdown is, I believe its indexed, its postgres and  not 100% sure what you mean on the text searches :/

Comment: And is row.id always the same in `tm.update(event_id: row.id)` (update_all)? Do you need callbacks? Validations?

Comment: If you don't need callbacks/validations: `TM.where(your_where_clauses).update_all(event_id: row.id)`

Comment: row.id changes , should have included the rest of the rake task, ITs doign an `Tablename.all.each do |row|` The row.id changes . accordingly

Comment: If you can't do the above (because you need callbacks/validations of your Rails app), I would suggest to use `find_each` and remove the `select(:id)` part. `find_each` does batch find (size of 1000 by default) so Rails does not load too much stuff in the memory (you are saying that Rails is loading 30k records at once, meaning it has to instanciate 30k times the same `TM` class to make 30k ruby objects -- that's a lot of wasted memory).

Comment: @SamRoberts it might change but does it change between each `TM` record found or is it the same for a bunch of `TM` records? ---- Actually, can you show us the whole code including the `Tablename.all.each` part?

Comment: The problem seems to be i'm only hitting around 15-20 querys per second in postgres. was looking for a way to speed this up?

Comment: @MrYoshiji There will be multiple tm records that assign to one row yes

Comment: @SamRoberts maybe too much RAM usage so PostgreSQL is slowed down? try removing the `select(:id)` part and use `tmarray.find_each` instead. give it a try

Comment: @MrYoshiji I'd move this to chat but i can't due to rep, Could you give an example? I don't understand where you would put find_each?

Comment: Is the column `valid_from` of type `string` or is it a date?

Comment: Someone needs to add the PostgreSQL equivalent of EXPLAIN in here. The OP could be missing indices for the SQL to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reduce the amount of records to load at once by Rails in memory by using `find_each` (https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Batches/find_each).

In your case, it would be:

```
tm_array = TM.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND valid_from = ? AND promotional_text ILIKE ?', "#{eventname}%", "#{row.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}", "#{row.eventvenuename}")
tm_array.find_each do |tm|
  tm.update(event_id: row.id)
end
```

---

**Edit** after your question update: Your whole task could become:

```
task populate: :environment do
  begin
    Event.find_each do |event| # << this changed from .all.each to .find_each
      eventname = event.eventname.gsub('UnderGround Presents ', '')
      eventname = eventname.gsub('&', 'and')
      tms = TM.where('product_name ILIKE ? AND valid_from = ? AND promotional_text ILIKE ?', "#{eventname}%", "#{event.date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}", "#{event.eventvenuename}")

      # Option 1
      tms.find_each do |tm|
        tm.update(event_id: event.id)
      end
      # Option 2 (if you do not need to run validations/callbacks on the TM records)
      tms.update_all(event_id: event.id)
    end
  rescue Faraday::TimeoutError
    puts 'Connection failed'
    next
  end
end
```

Suggested improvements:

- use `tms.update_all(event_id: event.id)` if you can (again, this won't run callbacks/validations so make sure it is not needed in your case) (it won't update the `updated_at` column also, but you can simply do `tms.update_all(event_id: event.id, updated_at: DateTime.now)`)
- make `valid_from` column of the TM model's table be a `date` type in the Database and use directly `event.date` without converting it to a specific formatted string
- create indexes on `product_name`, `valid_from` and `promotional_text` (see [`pg_trm` extension](https://niallburkley.com/blog/index-columns-for-like-in-postgres/) and enable the usage of `ILIKE` on indexed columns)
- replace `promotional_text ILIKE ?` with `promotional_text = ?` because the ILIKE is not needed (you search for the exact same name).

Comment: That made a huge difference, it dropeed it down to 7 seconds per 100 rows, Would be nicer if it was even faster but that helped alot more :)

Comment: Using `update_all` to update the records in a single query if possible is going to be an order of magnitude faster than doing thousands of update queries.

Comment: @SamRoberts see my updated answer. Like max suggested, use `update_all` and you will be able to execute this in few seconds only (the remaining choke point would be `Event.find_each`)